# Creating Stored Procedure to compare Date Column and update Status Column

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, plsql, cursor

I need a stored procedure to be created for comparing `EXPIRYDATE` column with `SYSTEMDATE` and if they match equal, then an additional column called `MATCHSTATUS` must be updated with value 1 and if they don't match then it must be update with value 0.

Both `EXPIRYDATE` and `MATCHSTATUS` are present in the same table.

Example:

```
username   password   expirydate   matchstatus
-----------------------------------------------------
abc        987        01-Feb-2015       1
xyz        678        10-Feb-2015       0
ghi        456        15-Jan-2015       0
```

In this example, the match status column should be update by comparing expirydate column with sysdate and it should be done by a stored procedure.

Comment: Why necessary a stored procedure?

Comment: so what's the problem?

Comment: You haven't actually asked a question, do you need help with the query to do this? Do you need help in how to create stored procedures? Do you want an opinion on if a Stored Procedure is that right method to use? Are you just making conversation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code can be something like that

```
Declare @crntdt NVARCHAR(20)
Declare @mydt NVARCHAR(20)

Select 
@crntdt = REPLACE(rtrim(ltrim(CONVERT(CHAR(15), getdate(), 106))),' ',' - ') 
--select @crntdt
select @mydt=expirydate from your_table

if @crntdt=@mydt
begin
update your_table set matchstatus=1 where expirydate=@mydt
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need I think - this assumes expirtydate is a date, if it's varchar you will need to cast it as a date:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_name
as
Begin
Update tbl
set matchstatus = case when expirydate = cast(GETDATE() as date) then 1 else 0 end
END
```